# Unix Vi editor I would like to remove the highlighted special symbol "|" pipe and replace with "," what command should I use here

Tags: unix

I would like to remove the Bold highlighted symbol "|" pipe from the text file in Unix vi editor and replace with "," qama

05:47|0|"Dolphin's Ref 11234/E/18 ~ "APL IPL" ~ Policy No. 2014-L124587-MCA **|** KK56347755 mcn62-534"|0|2|""|9|""|

Comment: I don't know why, but `:s/\|/,/g` seems to match every character. However, if you enclose the `\|` in square brackets, it seems to work properly: `:s/[\|]/,/g`